# Getting warning in 'eslint-plugin-react-settings' while running eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

Getting the:

> warning: React version specified in eslint-plugin-react-settings must be a valid semver version, or "detect"; got “latest”' while running eslint.

What is the reason behind this and how to resolve it?

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go9mn.png)

Comment: perhaps, fix your *eslint-plugin-react-settings* so it doesn't say *latest*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There will be an Object defined in your .eslintrc file as settings. And this error is saying that the version of react defined in it is not the version installed in your machine. Please replace settings object with following code so that es lint can detect it automatically on runtime.

```
"settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add the code in the .eslintrc file (js,json)
as this eslint will automatically detect the react version

```
"plugins": [
...
],
"settings": {
  "react": {
    "version": "detect"
  }
},
"rules": {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

adding this in my `.eslintrc` file fixed the problem.

```json
"settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
```